# Nservicebus 6 - Disable persistence

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5, nservicebus-configuration

Is there a way to disable persistence. I have a azure worker role endpoint that listens to events published on the azure service bus endpoint. So I do not want any persistence in my subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not a way to "disable" persistance but you can use "InMemoryPersistence" which should accomplish the same thing.

I always use the "InMemoryPersistence" option if I have an endpoint that is just going to do a send as there is no reason to have persistence for these endpoints.

Comment: This is right, I would also remind @hari-subramaniam that persistance performs other functions as well as event subscriptions, including supporting timeouts and saga data. I would double check you are not using any [persistence features](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/persistence/#storage-types) before using `InMemoryPersistence`